# omxplayer wrapper not working in open CV

Tags: opencv3.0, omxplayer

I am new to python coding & I am trying to run `omxplayer` wrapper in `openCV`.

[image: Omxplayer wrapper screenshot]

`omxplayer` wrapper working fine outside CV.

Sample code :

```
 from omxplayer import OMXPlayer
 from time import sleep
 file_path_or_url='rtsp://..'   IPCamera path
 player=OMXPlayer(file_path_or_url)
 player.play()
 sleep(5)
 player.pause()
 player.quit()
```

Environment details: 
[image: Environment details screenshot]

Comment: Try installing the module inside the `cv` virtual environment.